# Rebuilding Docker image taking time

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile has the following content,

```
FROM node:16.4.2-alpine3.14

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

COPY . /app
```

And ran the following **build command**,

```sh
docker build -t app:0.1 .
```

It took **28.4 seconds** and below is the terminal logs,

```
[+] Building 28.4s (10/10) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                     0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 124B                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring context: 53B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16.4.2-alpine3.14                                                                               17.1s
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2.01MB                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:16.4.2-alpine3.14@sha256:fabfca5e7dcb339097f998d6ef11c53dd80a3f99ed5cecc005e93d0ff6d4bda9                          9.9s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:16.4.2-alpine3.14@sha256:fabfca5e7dcb339097f998d6ef11c53dd80a3f99ed5cecc005e93d0ff6d4bda9                          0.0s
 => => sha256:fabfca5e7dcb339097f998d6ef11c53dd80a3f99ed5cecc005e93d0ff6d4bda9 1.00kB / 1.00kB                                                           0.0s
 => => sha256:75dec02064547a8ec570f2953e8d68a1674ad3f37730160f1570cce077be9ed0 1.16kB / 1.16kB                                                           0.0s
 => => sha256:40cb916373b08a087466d2e72402d0b3a4587fd3e9135169498cf0db4ff42a88 6.53kB / 6.53kB                                                           0.0s
 => => sha256:5843afab387455b37944e709ee8c78d7520df80f8d01cf7f861aae63beeddb6b 2.81MB / 2.81MB                                                           0.8s
 => => sha256:c118dce16b0057d713fc98e31606a84e4348fa2c967eaf1bb5fd21ba42825956 35.55MB / 35.55MB                                                         7.1s
 => => sha256:aef8e8137ac43c8199343c96874993063af6584260f22b15e99f735cce5de653 2.35MB / 2.35MB                                                           2.6s
 => => extracting sha256:5843afab387455b37944e709ee8c78d7520df80f8d01cf7f861aae63beeddb6b                                                                0.2s
 => => sha256:ad336e0e52b8dfc38c23599663deb060b1ac169d548dec8072ead94712f708be 281B / 281B                                                               2.0s
 => => extracting sha256:c118dce16b0057d713fc98e31606a84e4348fa2c967eaf1bb5fd21ba42825956                                                                2.0s
 => => extracting sha256:aef8e8137ac43c8199343c96874993063af6584260f22b15e99f735cce5de653                                                                0.2s
 => => extracting sha256:ad336e0e52b8dfc38c23599663deb060b1ac169d548dec8072ead94712f708be                                                                0.0s
 => [2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                   0.6s
 => [3/4] COPY package.json .                                                                                                                            0.1s
 => [4/4] COPY . /app                                                                                                                                    0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                   0.2s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                  0.2s
 => => writing image sha256:91d93eddff55cba6bd8b72144b7320e025de93e9865177ff584c75b94d1bafc1                                                             0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/app:0.1
```

When I run the same build command again, it is taking **14.6 seconds**.

However if I pull the **node:16.4.2-alpine3.14** using,

```sh
 docker pull node:16.4.2-alpine3.14
```

and then run the build command, then build takes only **0.3 seconds**

I think, when we build an image, dependencies also get downloaded and that is why the time taken reduces from **28.4** to **14.6** seconds. But why even **14.6** seconds? It should be as less as **0.3** seconds.

Why is this so? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

The following could be the reasons it takes ***18.4*** seconds:

1. Docker client takes the entire **build context** to the docker daemon.The build context is the entire directory the `Dockerfile`.some files or folders can take up a lot of space e.g `node_modules`. A remedy to this is to add the file that is not required eg *.git, node_module, log files* to the `.dockerignore` file to get Docker to ignore some files.
2. DNS resolution. Check how long it takes to resolve the docker registry using the `dig` command.
3. Enabling the buildkit for your build will help with improving the build time. Setting the `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` environment variable when invoking the docker build command such as:

> `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .`

please look at this [link for more information](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/)

Comment: Most time consuming part that I got from terminal,

```
#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16.4.2-alpine3.14
```


It took almost all the time.

I think it the problem with the WSL that I am using. I spin off a new ubuntu instance on VM and it is working fine now.